# SubVersion switch to depth

Tags: svn, branch, svn-switch

When switching from for example trunk to a branch, I get 5 different depth options.

- Only a folder
- Files in a folder
- Direct children
- Recursively
- Working copy

What's the difference between these? The first two should be fairly obvious, but not sure I get the difference between for example the last two.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have a look at this nice [documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html#tsvn-dug-checkout-depth). It explains all the depth options pretty well, for example:

- **Fully recursive** --
  Checkout the entire tree, including all child folders and sub-folders.
- **Immediate children, including folders** --
  Checkout the specified directory, including all files and child folders, but do not populate the child folders.
- **Only file children** --
  Checkout the specified directory, including all files but do not checkout any child folders.
- **Only this item** --
  Checkout the directory only. Do not populate it with files or child folders.
- **Working copy** --
  Retain the depth specified in the working copy. This option is not used in the checkout dialog, but it is the default in all other dialogs which have a depth setting.
- **Exclude** --
  Used to reduce working copy depth after a folder has already been populated. This option is only available in the Update to revision dialog.